# Run thrift in new thread cant catch the exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, thrift

I run thrift in a thread like this:

```
public static void start() {        
    Runnable simple = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            TProcessor tprocessor = new MessageForwardsService.Processor<MessageForwardsService.Iface>(new MessageForwardsRpcInterface());

            try {
                simple(tprocessor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(simple);
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {  

        @Override  
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {  
            System.out.println("Thread  uncaughtExceptionHandler catch a Exception**************************************************><><><><><><><><><<><><><><><");  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }); 
    t.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void simple(MessageForwardsService.Processor processor) {
    try {
    TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(WhrPublicConstants.RPC_PORT,2000);
        TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));

        System.out.println("Starting the rpc server... on port:"+WhrPublicConstants.RPC_PORT);
        server.serve();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The rpc method is:

```
    @Override
    public int emulateDevice( String msg) throws TException {
        throw new RuntimeException("just test throw exception");
        return 0;
    }
```

In the client side,I can get the error:
    org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

But in the thrift server side, I can't catch the exception as above.

Who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: To me, this sounds like it may possibly be a client-side connection problem. Have you checked to ensure that the host (I.E: 127.0.0.*, 192.168.*.*, etc.) and the port that you are connecting to are correct? The code that you've published all appears to be server-side, meanwhile you haven't posted any client-side code although the problem appears to be on the client-side.

Comment: Would you please post the full exception stack?

Comment: The problem is that the thrift server will catch your exception, serialize it and send it to the client, before it can reach the exception handler you set for the thread. What would you want to happen when a server-side exception occurs? Would you prefer to not send any reply to the client and let it time-out?